# Subgroups of semidirect product

Tags: group-theory

If a group $G$ is a direct product of two subgroups $U$ and $V$ such that $\lvert U \rvert$ and $\lvert V \rvert$ are coprime then any subgroup of $G$ is a direct product of subgroups of $U$ and $V$.

Now if $G$ is only a semidirect product, $\lvert U \rvert$ and $\lvert V \rvert$ still coprime, what can we say about the subgroups of $G$? Do they have a similar form?

Comment: I guess you must be talking about finite groups! The answer is yes, and it follows from the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem.

Comment: Thank you, but i am still wondering why this is true. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G = U \rtimes V$, do you consider $H\cap U$ and $H\cap V$ ?

Comment: It is probably necessary to take the conjugates of $V$ into account but even then to me it is not clear.

Comment: Yes that's right. If $V$ denotes a fixed complement of the normal subgroup $U$ in the semidirect product, then an arbitrary subgroup $H$ has the from $(H \cap U) \rtimes (H \cap V^u)$ for some $u \in U$. It is not necessarily of the form $(H \cap U) \rtimes (H \cap V)$. Sorry for not being clear about that.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G = U \rtimes V$, where $U$ and $V$ are finite groups of coprime order, and let $H \le G$.

So, if $\pi$ denotes the set of primes dividing $|U|$, then $U = O_\pi(G)$, and $U$ consists of the set of all $\pi$-elements of $G$. So $O_\pi(H) \le U $ and clearly $U \cap H \le O_\pi(H)$, so $O_\pi(H) = U \cap H$.

Now $H/O_\pi(H) = H/(H \cap U) \cong UH/U$ is a $\pi'$-group so, by the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem, $O_\pi(H)$ has a complement $C$ in $H$ and hence $H = (H \cap U) \rtimes C$.

Now, by the conjugacy part of the Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem (of which the proof depends on the Feit-Thompson Theorem that all groups of odd order are solvable, so we are using that here!), all complements of $U$ in $CU$ are conjugate, so $C$ is contained in a conjugate $V^g$ of $V$ and hence $H = (H \cap U) \rtimes (H \cap V^g)$.