# Subgroups of semi-direct products of two elementary abelian subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, abelian-groups, semidirect-product

**First question**: Let $H'$ be a subgroup of $H$ and $K'$ a subgroup of
$K$. Is it true that $H'\rtimes K'$ and $H'\times K'$ are subgroup of $H\rtimes
K$?

**Second question**: Let $G=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n}\rtimes
(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{m}$. What is the number of subgroups of
$G$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{2}$?

**Third question**: Is it true that if $\gcd (|H|,|K|)=1$ then all
subgroups of $H\rtimes K$ are of the form $H^{\prime }\rtimes K^{\prime }$.

Comment: For the first, I think you need that $K'$ is invariant under the action of $H'$. But I might be wrong on that.

Comment: Edited my answer to answer your new third question also.

Answer (score 1):

First question: If it exists, it's a subgroup, but since conjugation by elements of $K^{\prime}$ may take elements of $H^{\prime}$ to elements of $H\setminus H^{\prime}$, it need not exist.

Second question: That depends on the action involved in the semidirect product.  For example, consider $2^2\rtimes 2$.  If the action is trivial, we get $2^3$ which has seven subgroups isomorphic to $2^2$.  If the action is non-trivial, we get $D_4$, which has only two such subgroups.

(Note that $p^n$ is traditional shorthand for $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{n}$.)

Third question: No, since at the very least, if the action is non-trivial, $K$ has conjugates that intersect $H$ trivially and are not contained in $K$.

Comment: OK thank you very much. But what we can say about this answer math.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330088/subgroups-of-semidirect-product/1330267#1330267. Is it false.

Comment: It's fine, but it doesn't say that subgroups are of the form $H'\rtimes K'$  for $H'\le H$ and $K'\le K$.  It says there is some $g\in G$ (in fact we can take $g\in H$) such that a subgroup is of the form $H'\rtimes K'$ for $H\in H$ and $K'\in K^g$.